# Controlling the indent/offset for CMake in emacs

Tags: emacs, cc-mode

I am using cmake-mode which I thought came out of cc-mode (*ed: comments below indicate this was incorrect*). For some reason my indents (e.g. in an if() block) are coming out as 2 spaces, even though my c-basic-offset is set to 4. Does anybody know what/how to control this?

For example:

```
if( foo )
  set( a "bar" )
endif()
```

Comment: What's the value of `c-indentation-style`? `c-file-style`?

Comment: c-indentation-style is nil, also c-file-style

Comment: Can you share the content of a minimal source file that shows the problem?

Comment: `if( foo )
  set( a "bar" )
endif()` sorry no NL allowed in comments it seems, but my point is it happens in the simplest of blocks.

Comment: Comments do not preserve formatting; please edit the question and add the file content there instead.

Comment: Side note: `cmake-mode` is not based on `cc-mode`, so you can't use any of the cc-mode variables to configure it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indentation for `cmake-mode` seems to be controlled by the variable `cmake-tab-width`. You can adjust it like this:

```lisp
(setq cmake-tab-width 4)
```